Topbar Navigation drop downs move when screen is resized
The drop downs for the top bar navigation icons move awkwardly when you resize the screen:

I would think (and thought they use to) remain in place when resizing the screen.
Tested on Chrome Version 126.0.6478.127 and Firefox 127.0 across multiple SE sites.

The left menu "doesn't" move, in an entirely different but also wrong way

I can't reproduce the problem.

Repro'd on wide screen. Looks like the dropdown location is "fixed" to the browser window, but the icon is always centered to the top-bar, thus the discrepancy in the disposition.
